# CSS Image Sprite - Invalid Property Value

Tags: css, image, background, position, sprite

Learning to use sprite menu right now by following a tutorial. But for some reason, Chrome is giving me a 'invalid property value' on some of the background-position lines. The first one, with position 0 0 works fine, but the other two with -33 0 and 0 -33 won't work, which means my site is only showing 1 button right now and the hover isn't applied. The picture I am using right now is 197x65

```
  #sidebar .content .follow a {
                            display: block; float: left; height: 32px;
                            background-image: url('http://s23.postimg.org/8ltupgj0r/follow.png'); text-indent: -9999px;  
                            margin-right: 5px;
                            }

                           #sidebar .content .follow a.fb {
                               width: 32px; background-position: 0 0; }
                           #sidebar .content .follow a.twit {
                               width: 32px; background-position: -33 0; }

                           #sidebar .content .follow a.fb:hover {
                               background-position: 0 -33; }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the background-position properties you need to set what value type you are wanting, px, em, etc. CSS understands the 0 but you need to be more specific for the other values.

```
#sidebar .content .follow a.twit {
    width: 32px; background-position: -33px 0; }
#sidebar .content .follow a.fb:hover {
    background-position: 0 -33px; }
```

Comment: Guess they left that out in the tutorial, I should have figured it out. Thanks for the fast answer!